# How to draw a ring using canvas in android?

Tags: android

Can anybody suggest me how to draw a ring using canvas methods. I may draw to circles using `canvas.drawCircle()` but how should I feel a space between them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. You can draw a circle with a thick brush (use [setStrokeWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth%28float%29)).
2. You can draw two circles, one inside another. One filled with 'ring' color, and another (inner one) filled with screen 'background color'

Comment: If u use first method don't forget set style paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

Comment: Also note that the stroke starts drawing from the edge of the shape. If you have a thick stroke, the edges will get clipped. To fix this, take the stroke size into account when specifying the ring's radius.

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin you can do:

- define your paint with stroke style whitin the init block

```kotlin
class CustomView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

private var ringPaint: Paint
  init {
        ringPaint = Paint()
        ringPaint.color = R.color.RED // Your color here
        ringPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE // This is the important line
        ringPaint.strokeWidth = 20f // Your stroke width in pixels
  }

}
```

- draw your circle in the onDraw method by using drawCircleFunction (centerX,centerY,radius,paint)

```kotlin
override fun draw(canvas: Canvas?) {
            super.draw(canvas)
            canvas?.drawCircle(width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f, (width - 10) / 2.0f, ringPaint)
        }
```